# Convert org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 to java.lang.String

Tags: java, avro

I write a sample with avro library. It generate java class source code `User` from schema `record User`.

I want to encode `User` to `byte[]`, and decode `byte[]` to `User`.

When decoding, I've got error message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

How to convert `org.apache.avro.util.Utf8` to java `String` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use its method [toString()](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/org/apache/avro/util/Utf8.html#toString())

> toString in interface CharSequence

Comment: Hi, if the value is a avro GenericRecord, is there a `toGenericRecord()` method ?

Comment: @linrongbin see code examples https://www.codota.com/code/java/classes/org.apache.avro.util.Utf8